# Linq Query custom where condition for Join?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables 
User, 
Role, 
Department

User Table have Id, Name, IsDisable, Role_Id, Department_Id

Role Table have Id, Name, IsDisable

Department Table Have Id, Name, IsDisable

I am to joining the table as per request, In request only I will get to know which table I should join. So I am joining tables dynamic and taking the value.
But now I have to search for the free text.Now I have to find in the Joined Table "Name" Columns containing some text for example :('%G%'). How to achieve that?

```
IQueryable<User> query=  _odb.User.Where(a=>!a.IsDisable);

if(request.RoleNeeded)
{
    query=from qu in query
    join ro in _odb.Role on us.Role_Id equals Role.Id
    select qu
}

if(request.DepartmentNeeded)
{
    query=from qu in query
    join de in _odb.Department on us.Department_Id equals Department.Id
    select qu
}
```

How to do the Where condition for 'like' with 'or' condition dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Try Code

Add Left Join in Linq query and Inside To Where case.

```
IQueryable<User> query=  _odb.User.Where(a=>!a.IsDisable);

if(request.RoleNeeded)
{
   query=from qu in query
   join ro in _odb.Role on qu.Role_Id equals ro .Id
   join de in _odb.Department on qu.Department_Id equals de.Id into jj from kk in jj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where where (qu.Name.contains("G") || ro.Name.contains("G") || de.Name.contains("G"))
   select qu
}

if(request.DepartmentNeeded)
{
   query=from qu in query
   join de in _odb.Department on qu.Department_Id equals de.Id
   join ro in _odb.Role on qu.Role_Id equals ro .Id into jj from kk in jj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where where (qu.Name.contains("G") || ro.Name.contains("G") || de.Name.contains("G"))
   select qu
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need the where condition for all name I need it only for the table I am joining. For Example, if I join User and Role than I need to search in the Role name and User Name, If I join User and Department then User Name and Department Name. If I join all then I want it in all three Name columns. That condition has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to possibly end up going to SQL (Linq2SQL, EF, etc.) then it can pay to minimize the potential SQL with a little deliberate selective code This requires setting up the mapping so the relationships between data objects are known. (Assuming EF or Linq2SQL)

```
var matchingUsers = _odb.User.Where(u=> false == u.IsDisable && u.Name.Contains("G"));
var matchingRoles = _odb.User.Where(u=> false == u.IsDisable && u.Roles.Any(r=> r.Name.Contains("G"));
var matchingDepartments = _odb.User.Where(u=> false == u.IsDisable && u.Departments.Any(r=> r.Name.Contains("G"));

// The above queries will not have executed yet until we call a ToList, FirstOrDefault, etc.

// Set up which results we are interested in by unioning based on the request.
var query = matchingUsers;
if (request.RoleNeeded)
  query = query.Union(matchingRoles);
if (request.DepartmentNeeded)
  query = query.Union(matchingDepartments);

//Executes and returns our requested matches.
return query.ToList();
```

It should be possible alternatively to work out a single where clause, but it would end up involving null conditionals being sent to the DB resulting in a more complex execution plan.

Comment: Yeah, Union will have a side effect, It affects the performance, It is a good solution but I can't use this.